# A inclusão de dados não ta ocorrendo no banco, sendo que a conexão e a variável tá chegando na função

Tags: php, mysqli

function gravar_tarefa($conexao, $tarefa) {
        if(mysqli_connect_error($conexao)){

```
    echo 'Sem conexão com banco de dados';

    die();
}
$sqlGravar = " INSERT INTO tarefas (nome, descricao, prioridade) VALUES ( '{$tarefa['nome']}', '{$tarefa['descricao']}', '{$tarefa['prioridade']}' ) ";
mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlGravar);
```

}

Comment: Bem a principio vc pode tentar capturar o erro igual fez com a conexão ... `if (!mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlGravar);) {
    printf("Erro: %s", mysqli_error($conexao));
}`

Comment: Obrigado, não tinha visto seu comentário. Mas com ele achei a solução do problema. Tava no Html que tava passando o valor errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","roo","","test");
$tarefa = array("nome"=>"a", "descricao"=>"b", "prioridade"=>"c");

gravar_tarefa($conexao, $tarefa);

function gravar_tarefa($conexao, $tarefa){ 
    $nome = 'nome'; 
    $descricao = 'descricao'; 
    $prioridade = 'prioridade'; 

    if(mysqli_connect_error($conexao)){

        echo 'Sem conexão com banco de dados';

        die();
    }

for ($i=0; $i < count($tarefa); $i++) { 
$sqlGravar = <<<INSERT
    INSERT INTO teste (nome, descricao, prioridade) VALUES ( '$tarefa[nome]', '$tarefa[descricao]', '$tarefa[prioridade]' )
INSERT;
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlGravar);
}

    if($result==true){
        echo "Dados Salvos";
    }else{
        echo "dados não salvos";
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas os dados que são incluídos não são fixo é passado por parâmetro em um array

Comment: adicionei a array veja se te ajuda

Comment: Teste não funcionou, ai fiz o teste $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tarefas (nome, descricao, prioridade) VALUES ('cu','rato','pelo' )");
 if ($resultado){
  echo "funcionou";
 }else{
  echo "não funcionou";
 }
 ?> e com <<<INSERT e tbm não funcionou pode ser o banco e não o código ???

Comment: sim pode ser a sua tabela posta a estrutura dela

Comment: Obrigado me ajudaram muito.

Comment: Marca resposta como util ;)

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Testei com o código do Raul Fernando e funcionou normal. Certifique de que seu banco de dados esteja criado corretamente e se as tabelas correspondem ao seu código. Testado em PHP 7.

Comment: Obrigado me ajudaram muito.